# Qt Slot and signal are not connected: No such signal

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to deal with slots and signals in Qt, for this I am trying to do the following:
The *MyTestClass* class should send a signal to the *ReceiverClass* class, the code:

**mytestclass.h**

```
class MyTestClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyTestClass();
    void makeSignal();
signals:
    void sendSignal();
};
```

**mytestclass.cpp**

```
MyTestClass::MyTestClass()
{
}

void MyTestClass::makeSignal()
{
    emit sendSignal();
}
```

**reseiverclass.h**

```
class ReceiverClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ReceiverClass();
public slots:
    void receiverSlot();
};
```

**reseiverclass.cpp**

```
ReceiverClass::ReceiverClass()
{
}

void ReceiverClass::receiverSlot()
{
    qInfo() << "receiverSlot called!\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
...
MyTestClass testObj;
ReceiverClass receiverObj;

QObject::connect(&testObj, SIGNAL(&testObj::sendSignal()), &receiverObj, SLOT(&receiverObj::receiverSlot));

testObj.makeSignal();
...
```

However, I encounter such an error.
Why doesn't Qt see the signal?

```
QObject::connect: No such signal MyTestClass::&testObj::sendSignal() in ..\testQtProject\main.cpp:15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QObject::connect(&testObj, SIGNAL(&testObj::sendSignal()), &receiverObj, SLOT(&receiverObj::receiverSlot));
```

You are mixing the syntax of the 2 methods for connecting signal and slots in Qt, either use :

```
QObject::connect(&testObj, SIGNAL(sendSignal()), &receiverObj, SLOT(receiverSlot()));
```

or

```
QObject::connect(&testObj, &testObj::sendSignal, &receiverObj, &receiverObj::receiverSlot);
```

For more informations, look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html and https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will read this in more detail.